# Shell script not running from jenkins file

Tags: shell, jenkins, devops

When I run the shell script from the Jenkins File in my windows machine

I am getting an error saying

> ---"Cannot run program "nohup" (in directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\testjf_master"): CreateProcess error=2, The
>   system cannot find the file specified"

Sh command is running from my cmd, so I guess right path defined in ENV

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('stage A') {
      steps {
        echo 'this is stage A, my  demo value is $demo'
        sh 'echo "this is $BUILD_NUMBER of demo $demo"'
      }
    }

  }
  environment {
    demo = '08'
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll need bat or powershell instead of "sh"

Comment: I am going to with `nohup` is a unix command and `C:\Program Files\` is a Windows machine, so won't be found. Search S/O for ["[jenkins] nohup 'c:\' is:question"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjenkins%5D+nohup+%27c%3A%5C%27+is%3Aquestion) for suggestions to fix.